# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime error in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate date diff and getting below error.

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Below is my code

```
select (CONVERT(DECIMAL,((dbo.convertToUnixTime(GETDATE())-tr.created))))/86400
from Allreporting  tr
```

Comment: Show the data and definitions of the objects of the query.

Comment: @Serg 2018-11-20 17:25:25.000 is the format of created. Created is a datetime column

Comment: @Serg I want to get days open from the above query.So using datediff from current date to create date

Comment: can you show us value of `dbo.convertToUnixTime(GETDATE())` please

Comment: Hi @Ven 1567587455 is the value of dbo.convertToUnixTime(GETDATE())

Comment: How could you compare big int to datetime, tr.created is datetime if i am not wrong

Comment: @ven created is datetime Yes

Comment: What's the point of this code? What are you trying to calculate and why is that custom `convertToUnixTime` method used? SQL Server doesn't use or need Unix timestamps. All major databases have date types so there's no need to use integers or strings instead of actual dates, timezones etc.

Comment: so this means you are actually doing this `1567587455 - '2018-11-20 17:25:25.000'`,this doesn't work. either you convert both to same format and convert to int

Comment: @Krish If you want to count the number of days, months, hours etc between two date-related types use [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). A simple `select DATEDIFF(day,tr.Created,GETDATE()) from Allreporting  tr` will just work. This function works with all date types (eg datetime2, date, datetimeoffset, time etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `datediff` Demo:

```
select datediff(dd,cast ('2018-11-20 17:25:25.000' as datetime) /* tr.created*/, getdate()) days
```